# Spring Cloud Consumer argument payload is always getting byte array object

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm using Spring Cloud Edgware. SR3 and Spring Cloud Stream 2.0.1 Release.

I have created testprocessor app using spring cloud stream 2.0.
    Created the sample stream:

```
stream create TEST1 --definition "http --server.port=8888 | testprocessor | uploader --spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.contentType='text/plain1' "
```

Deployed in Spring cloud local server.

```
//testprocessor apps method signature is
@StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
@sendto(Processor.OUTPUT)
public String transform(Object payload) {

}
```

In application.properties of this app, i have configured below properties
`spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.content-type=application/json;`

Sample input data:

```
http post --contentType 'application/json' --data '{\"isbn\": \"1599869772", "title": "The Art of War", "author": "Sun Tzu"}' --target http://localhost:8888
```

When i post above sample data, i am always getting Object payload is `byte[]` object like `[B@5b2ff6e7` but not getting actual JSON String.
Please can you help on this issue?

Note: If i build same testprocessor app using spring cloud stream 1.3.1 version. It is working fine. I am getting JSON string. Why it is not working using spring cloud stream 2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

The `transformer` application has an `expression` option, so you can do like this:

```
--expression='new String(payload)'
```

And you'll get a JSON string there in the `public String transform(Object payload)` method.

The related GH issue: https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/transform/issues/6